# Take infrared photo with digital camera?

Tags: infrared

With a film camera it is easy to take infrared photos, just get infrared film.

Is there any way to do this with a standard professional digital camera?

My understanding is that such cameras have a 700-1000nm filter to block infrared light. Can this filter be removed somehow?

Comment: Related: [Are infrared DSLR conversion companies safe? What about DIY infrared conversion?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/9339)

Comment: Related: [What are the benefits of infrared conversion?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/11211)

Answer (score -1):

Yes there are a number of companies that will convert some digital cameras to IR. they will remove the blocking filter and replace it with a piece of glass. with some of these conversions you will need to use an IR filter on the lens.
 note. film IR was not easy. you had set everything up then put a filter on the lens and hope you did not mess up the focus. the filters were opaque.

Comment: I thought that IR filters *are just panes of glass*. Glass blocks IR. If you look at a car with an IR camera, the windows are black.

Comment: Glass blocks UV (most of it). It lets IR pass (most of it).

Comment: Sigma SD15 or similar: 
https://blog.sigmaphoto.com/2012/sigma-sd1-and-sd15-for-digital-infrared-photography-by-jack-howard/

Comment: Tyler what you are thinking of is called a hot mirror

Comment: http://www.kodak.com/motion/products/lab_and_post_production/kodak_filters/wratten_2_filters/default.htm#s6